# Having trouble getting my code to find the inverse of a matrix using gauss elimination

Tags: c

having trouble with my code basically, have to get the inverse of a n*n matrix by creating an augmented matrix with the identity matrix and Gaussian elimination(no swapping of row) to get the inverse would really appreciate any help. Code needs to be in c by the way and need to use Gaussian elimination for purpose of this assignment

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n = 3;

    float matrix[10][10];
    float augmatrix[10][10];
    /*creating random matrix*/
    for(int i=0;i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j]= i+(j*j)+1;

        }

     }
     /*creating an augmented matrix with identity matrix*/
        for (int i=0;i<n; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<2*n; j++)
            {
                if(j<n)
                {
                    augmatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];

                }
                else if(i==j-n)
                {
                    augmatrix[i][j] = 1.0;

                }
                else
                {
                    augmatrix[i][j] = 0.0;

                }

          }

       }
         /*printing matrix*/
    printf("matrix is \n");
    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
        {
            printf(" %f", matrix[z][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("augmatrix is \n");
    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < n*2; x++)
        {
            printf(" %f", augmatrix[z][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
         /*gausian elimination*/
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(i!=j){
                int l = augmatrix[j][i]/augmatrix[i][i];
                for(int k = 0; k < 2*n; k++){
                    augmatrix[j][k] -= l * augmatrix[i][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        float a = augmatrix[i][i];
        for(int j = 0; j < 2*n; j++){
            augmatrix[i][j] /= a;
        }
    }
       /*print result*/
    printf("matrix is \n");
    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < n*2; x++)
        {
            printf(" %f", augmatrix[z][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. As it stands, your code is difficult to read.

Comment: Also, "having trouble" is not descriptive enough. You need to provide a set of input, expected output, present output. Read more on how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: `int l` should be a `float`, otherwise you will only get whole numbers. Also note that `augmatrix[i][i]` will have changed once `j` is greater than `i`, so you probably need to save the diagonal value at the beginning of the loop over `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with doing

```
for(int i=0;i<n; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j]= i+(j*j)+1;
    }

 }
```

is that you are generating a matrix for which an inverse will not exist.

Use random numbers to generate the matrix and have a check to see that the determinant is non zero.